# How to sum the value of skipped datetime based on IntervalIndex?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

Suppose I have two dataframe `df1` and `df2`

In `df1`

```
   date                 value
0  2018-01-23 10:00:00  10
1  2018-01-23 10:05:00  20
2  2018-01-23 10:10:00  30
3  2018-01-23 10:15:00  40
4  2018-01-23 10:20:00  50
```

In `df2`

```
   date                 value
0  2018-01-23 10:02:00  10
1  2018-01-23 10:03:00  20
2  2018-01-23 10:04:00  30
3  2018-01-23 10:05:00  40
4  2018-01-23 10:16:00  50
5  2018-01-23 10:17:00  60
```

First I get IntervalIndex (left closed, right open) based on `df1.date` and for each interval I need to calculate the summation of `df2.value` and map the summation to the `df1`.

Edit:
The code I used:

```
shift_date = df1.date.shift(-1)
shift_date[-1] = df1.date.iloc[-2] + timedelta(minutes=5) #avoid NaT
idx = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df1.date, shift_date, closed = "left")
df2_sum = df2.loc[idx.get_indexer(df1.date), 'value']
df2_sum = df2_sum.groupby(df2_sum.index).sum()
```

but only got the value of `df1` mapped to `df2.index`.

What I am looking for looks like

```
   date                 value df2_value
0  2018-01-23 10:00:00  10    60
1  2018-01-23 10:05:00  20    40
2  2018-01-23 10:10:00  30    0
3  2018-01-23 10:15:00  40    0
4  2018-01-23 10:20:00  50    110
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First create `IntervalIndex` and for remove `NaT` fillna by some future date like `2100-01-01`:

```
df1.index = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df1.date,
                                         df1.date.shift(-1).fillna(pd.datetime(2100,1,1)), 
                                         closed = "left")
print (df1)
                                                          date  value
[2018-01-23 10:00:00, 2018-01-23 10:05:00) 2018-01-23 10:00:00     10
[2018-01-23 10:05:00, 2018-01-23 10:10:00) 2018-01-23 10:05:00     20
[2018-01-23 10:10:00, 2018-01-23 10:15:00) 2018-01-23 10:10:00     30
[2018-01-23 10:15:00, 2018-01-23 10:20:00) 2018-01-23 10:15:00     40
[2018-01-23 10:20:00, 2100-01-01)          2018-01-23 10:20:00     50
```

Then use [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) with groupby and aggregate `sum`:

```
df3 = df2.groupby(pd.cut(df2.date, bins=df1.index))['value'].sum().rename('df2_value')
print (df3)
date
[2018-01-23 10:00:00, 2018-01-23 10:05:00)     60
[2018-01-23 10:05:00, 2018-01-23 10:10:00)     40
[2018-01-23 10:10:00, 2018-01-23 10:15:00)      0
[2018-01-23 10:15:00, 2018-01-23 10:20:00)    110
[2018-01-23 10:20:00, 2100-01-01)               0
Name: df2_value, dtype: int64
```

Both indices are same, so is possible remove it and `concat`:

```
df = pd.concat([df1.reset_index(drop=True), df3.reset_index(drop=True)], axis=1)
print (df)
                 date  value  df2_value
0 2018-01-23 10:00:00     10         60
1 2018-01-23 10:05:00     20         40
2 2018-01-23 10:10:00     30          0
3 2018-01-23 10:15:00     40        110
4 2018-01-23 10:20:00     50          0
```

Answer (score 0):

A little bit simpler:

```
ii = pd.IntervalIndex.from_breaks(df1['date'], closed='left')
res = df2.groupby(ii.get_indexer(df2['date']))['value'].sum()
df1['df2_value'] = res.reindex(df1.index, fill_value=0)
```

The resulting output for `df1`:

```
                 date  value  df2_value
0 2018-01-23 10:00:00     10         60
1 2018-01-23 10:05:00     20         40
2 2018-01-23 10:10:00     30          0
3 2018-01-23 10:15:00     40        110
4 2018-01-23 10:20:00     50          0
```